# When debuggin with Protractor, how how do I get the original selector used when element fails to find the DOM node?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to debug a test flow in an Angular (1.x) app that involves a number of actions across several pages.  At some point, Protractor throws a "could not find element" error.  It would be great to know how to get it to print out the css selector used when it errors so I could easier track down the failure in my test code.  Is there a way to do this?

The complicating factor is that there are a few automatic redirects in the app (click 'submit' form then stuff happens) that makes it tricky to know exactly which page to debug.

So something like this would be great:

```
var elem = element(by.css('.some-elem'));
elem.getSelector();  // return '.some-elem', or another way to sniff out the element instance
```

Hopefully that is clear, if not I would be happy to elaborate more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `element().locator().toString()` to find the locator used by the element.it works for both `element()` and `element.all()`.

```
var element1 = element(by.css("someCss"));
element1.locator().toString(); //this will return you `by.css("someCss")`
```

it is always advisable to follow page object pattern while scripting the test cases which in turn will make your test suite more easy to maintain.

Comment: nice, I use `locator()` a lot but never tried with `.toString()`.  Much cleaner result

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have used.

```
var elem = element(by.css('.some-elem'));
elem.parentElementArrayFinder.locator_.toString();
```